# char in string is not in order wanted

Tags: string

I am a beginner and I need some help here. This program prints out the frequency of char in the string, e.g. if user enters `zzaaa` it prints out `a3z2` and what I need to print is `z2a3` since `z` is entered first before `a`. But I am having a hard time switching the order around. Thanks in advance!

```
int main
{
    int ib, i=0, j=0, k=0;
    int count[26] = {0};
    char chh[3][10];

    for (ib = 0; ib < 3; ib++) // get 3 input
        gets(chh[ib]);

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{

    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (chh[i][j] >= 'a' && chh[i][j] <= 'z')
        {
            count[chh[i][j] - 'a']++;
        }
    }


    for (k = 0; k < 26; k++)
    {
        if (count[k] != 0) // if array location is not equals to 0
            printf("%c%d", k + 'a', count[k]); 
    }

    memset(count, 0, sizeof(count)); //reset integer array
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: what is `B` in `gets(B[ib])`?

Comment: used undefined array `B[ib]`, `chh[3][10]` contents unknown!

Comment: hi sorry B should be chh i have changed it.

Comment: hi what does it means ib is not intialized. sorry im quite new to programming.

Comment: sory my bad, I didn't see the for loop.

Comment: A quick fix would be, to make `count[26][2];` and then place the position of the word in `count[26][1]`,(word count in `count[26][0]`), then sort from low to high and print it

Comment: Please do not ever use `gets()` as a function.  It cannot be used safely.  It is no longer a part of standard C.  Pretend that it will crash your program if you use it.  Use `fgets()` instead, but remember that `fgets()` includes a newline and `gets()` does not.  Or, on Windows, consider using `gets_s()` instead (removes newline and can be used safely). Also, you should always check the return value from an input function so that you do not try using a value if the function did not succeed in reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prints `a` before `z` because you arranged `count` from `a` to `z` by alphabetic priority not entering priority:

```
count[chh[i][j] - 'a']
```

if you want to print them by entering priority you should change it. there are several ways to do this. like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int ib, i=0, j=0,k=0, kk=0,c=0,found=0;
    int count[26][2];
    char chh[3][10];
    for (ib = 0; ib < 3; ib++) // get 3 input
        gets(chh[ib]);

    printf("output is:\n");

for (i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        count[i][0]=0;
        count[i][1]=0;
    }
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {

        if (chh[i][j] >= 'a' && chh[i][j] <= 'z')
        {

            found=0;
            for (c=0;c<kk;c++)
                if (count[c][0]==chh[i][j])
                        {

                            count[c][1]++;
                            found=1;
                            break;
                        }

            if (!found)
                {

                    count[c][0]=chh[i][j];
                    count[c][1]++;

                    kk++;
                }

        }
    }


    for (k = 0; k < 26; k++)
    {
        if (count[k][1] != 0) // if array location is not equals to 0
            printf("%c%d", count[k][0], count[k][1]); 
    }

   memset(count, 0, sizeof(count)); //reset integer array
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: hi million thanks it works! but can i know what does this line does? count[c][0]=chh[i][j]

Comment: it means that save this character in `count`. when it's a new character